# Remove Invite code in link when I create permission google driver API C#

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

When I use Google drive api [Permissions: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create) method.

The system sends a notification email to the invitees.

When I use an account other than the email account added and accessed the link above and I can access that folder.

[image: This is the picture when I click to link].

I see at the end of the there is one more param:

> **&invite=CNaXrZcM&ts=5f87c5d4**

I need to remove it.

[image: Here is my code]

Comment: please edit your question and include your code not an image of your code.   Im not sure what your issues is or what you want to remove.

Answer (score 1):

When  you create permissions for a file google sends the person who the permission was created for an email.

This email was generated by google and contains a link that their system can use in order to accept the permissions.

The key hear being that a user must accept the permissions before a file simply is shows up their google drive account.

The link created contains several prams that the system at Google needs, you have no control over this link and there is no way to remove the prams that you are speaking of.

Comment: Thanks for your support, maybe I'll turn off mailing notifications to secure my directory.